# Hide Password From Console Window Java Asterisk Password Or Block Inputted String Being Displayed

Tags: java, input, console, passwords

```
public class Login {

    protected static String user, pass, host;
    Object conn;


    public void Login() throws SQLException
    {



    try {
      Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println ("Could not load the driver"); 
      }




    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Console console = System.console();

    System.out.println("Please Enter Username");
    user = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Password");
    pass = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Host/IP Address");
    host = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Attempting Log In");



  Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection
                  ("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/chessdb", user, pass);
```

Just bit of help, been looking around online at blocking the password being shown on the console window. Is there a simple method of either the inputted text not appearing at all or else an asterisk to cover the input of the password field only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `readPassword()` method.

instead of using **scanner** like

```
System.out.println("Please Enter Password");
    pass = sc.nextLine();
```

use:

```
    System.out.println("Please Enter Password");
    char[] passString = Console.readPassword();
    String pass = new String(passString );
```

Comment: NullPointerException error in java.lang  --> error message receiving

Comment: are you running the program using any IDE?  is so , please execute it from command line

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.io.Console.readPassword()` method

See API in below link

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

Answer (score 0):

[`java.io.Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) has a method for reading passwords with output disabled: [`Console#readPassword`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword()).